# Merge two columns from different tables in same column

Tags: sql, merge

I want to merge two columns in same columns from two different tables.

Using SQL, I have used join but not helpful any more.

Here is a detailed case :

I have a `sellDetailTable` and `buyDetailTable`

`buy` table

```
+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
|buyId         | supplier  name     | productId | QtyIn     |  price          |
+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
```

`sell details` table

```
+--------+--------+----------+-------+------+
|sellId  |  client|productId |QtyOut | price|
+--------+--------+----------+-------+------+
```

I want to merge them like so

```
+---------------+------------------+----------+----------+-------+-----------+
|sellId or buyId|supplier or client|productId | QtyIn    | QtyOut| price     |
+---------------+------------------+----------+----------+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: please put up your code here.... and also table format..... like whatever you have applied to table columns..... and one more thing... please SPECIFY in which sql program you are working....

Comment: i'm devlopping an inventory managment system using sqlite and qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a UNION query:

```
SELECT buyId, suppliername, productId, QtyIn, 0, price
UNION
SELECT sellId, client, productId, 0, QtyOut, price
```

and, if you want, insert that into your new table, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO sellBuyTable(buyOrSellId, supplierOrclient, productId, qtyIn, qtyOut, price)
<query above>
```